# Watin cannot launch IE9

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-9, watin

I’m using WatiN and MS Unit test for the automation work. During the development, I find this strange issue:

Sometimes, I cannot launch IE9 and the test project shows “In Progress” status. But when I restart my computer, it works well.

The assembly version is: 2.1.0. The code is like the below:

```
IE ie = new IE(url);     
ie.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Maximize);
ie.WaitForComplete();
```

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to close all IE instances first, there may be some processes running that are not visible which can disrupt things.

Call this function before your code above

```
public void CloseAll()
{
    while (IE.InternetExplorersNoWait().Count > 0)
    {
        var ie = IE.InternetExplorersNoWait()[0];
        ie.ForceClose();
    }
}
```

Comment: That resolves my issue. It explains when i restarted the computer, it works well. Thanks very much.

Comment: @GaryWang  Looks like you're new to stackoverflow, you should take a read of the http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask  It'd be etiquette for you to upvote and mark this as the answer if it answers your question, which it seemed to.  You'll find this would help your general karma and it is the structured way to express your thanks rather than a comment.